# Selenium Python Stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm trying to make a program that works on flickr I have everything working up until the cookies popup which is defeating me.

```
   <iframe src="https://consent-pref.trustarc.com/?type=flickr_iab&amp;layout=iab&amp;site=flickr.com&amp;action=notice&amp;country=gb&amp;locale=en&amp;behavior=expressed&amp;gtm=1&amp;iab=true&amp;irm=undefined&amp;from=https://consent.trustarc.com/" id="pop-frame016812901338164787" title="TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager" tabindex="1" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px none; border-radius: 2px; overflow: hidden; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 834px;"></iframe>
```

I'm trying to switch to this iframe so I can then use the 'Accept All' button. However the ID for the iframe is dynamic so to get around this I tried to target the title instead.

```
xpath = """//iframe[contains(@title, 'TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager')]"""
iframe = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath);

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe);
```

However I now get this error message.

```
 File "flickrbot.py", line 28, in <module>
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe);
  File "C:\Users\IMFro\.virtualenvs\Desktop-LBlgM1Hj\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 89, in frame
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_FRAME, {'id': frame_reference})
  File "C:\Users\IMFro\.virtualenvs\Desktop-LBlgM1Hj\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\IMFro\.virtualenvs\Desktop-LBlgM1Hj\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

I have tried adding a wait of 10 seconds to give it time to load and I understand the reason for the error is that the element is no longer attached to the DOM but I don't know what other reference to use.

Any suggestions would be a great help! Also i'm incredibly new to python so if you could tell me like you are explaining to a 5 year old that would be greatly appreciated ahahaha

Answer (score 0):

You may try with `explicit waits`  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@title, 'TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager')]")))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the reply! Annoyingly it still won't work the wait times out :(

Comment: Can I have the actual url ?

Comment: Hey sure!! It's www.flickr.com